# How to swap the last two column pairs with awk?

Tags: awk, cygwin

I am trying this

```sh
awk '{B=$(NF-1);A=$NF;  $NF=$(NF-2); $(NF-1) = $(NF-3); $(NF-2)=A; $(NF-3) = B; print;}' input_text.txt
```

but I get the error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=cazzo.txt FNR=2) fatal: attempt to access field -1
```

Sample input:

```
$ cat input_text.txt
1 7 9 11 0 5 2
```

The same happens if I replace the `spaces` with `tabs` in the `input_text.txt` file.

Expected output:

```
 1 7 9 5 2 11 0
```

I am running with `Cygwin` on `Windows 10`.

Comment: Use this: `awk 'NF>3 {B=$(NF-1);A=$NF;  $NF=$(NF-2); $(NF-1) = $(NF-3); $(NF-2)=A; $(NF-3) = B} 1' input_text.txt`

Comment: That just removed the first three columns. :(  The output of `awk 'NF>3 {B=$(NF-1);A=$NF;  $NF=$(NF-2); $(NF-1) = $(NF-3); $(NF-2)=A; $(NF-3) = B} 1' input_text.txt` is this:  `11 0 5 2`

Comment: I just edited the question by adding the desired output :)

Comment: If your text file uses DOS `\r\n` line endings, you'll have to remove the `\r` from $NF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `awk` for swapping values:

```sh
awk 'NF > 3 {a=$NF; b=$(NF-1); $NF=$(NF-2); $(NF-1)=$(NF-3); $(NF-3)=b; $(NF-2)=a} 1' file

1 7 9 5 2 11 0
```

If there are DOS line breaks then use:

```sh
awk -v RS='\r?\n' 'NF > 3 {a=$NF; b=$(NF-1); $NF=$(NF-2); $(NF-1)=$(NF-3); $(NF-3)=b; $(NF-2)=a} 1' file
```

---

If you have `gnu awk` then you can use this regex based approach:

```sh
awk -v RS='\r?\n' 'NF > 3 {
$0 = gensub(/(\S+\s+\S+)(\s+)(\S+\s+\S+)$/, "\\3\\2\\1", "1")} 1' file

1 7 9 5 2 11 0
```

Answer (score 2):

To swap the last `n` fields with the `n` fields before them:

```
$ awk -v n=2 'NF>=(2*n){ for (i=NF-(n-1); i<=NF; i++) {t=$i; $i=$(i-n); $(i-n)=t} } 1' file
1 7 9 5 2 11 0

$ awk -v n=3 'NF>=(2*n){ for (i=NF-(n-1); i<=NF; i++) {t=$i; $i=$(i-n); $(i-n)=t} } 1' file
1 0 5 2 7 9 11
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following code. This is a Generic code, where you have 2 `awk` variables named `fromFields` and `toFields`. So you need to give their values like: let's say you want to substitute 4th field value with 6th field AND 5th field value with 7th field, so you will set it like: `fromFields="4,5"` and `toFields="6,7"`. I am assuming user will understand that values which are given are feasible with respect to Input_file.

```
awk -v fromFields="4,5" -v toFields="6,7" '
BEGIN{
  num1=split(fromFields,arr1,",")
  num2=split(toFields,arr2,",")
}
{
  tmp=""
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){
    tmp=$arr1[i]
    $arr1[i]=$arr2[i]
    $arr2[i]=tmp
  }
}
1
' Input_file
```

Comment: @Ubaldo Tiberi, could you please do let me know if my answer has worked for you?